# Processingjs and WebGL

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, processing, paperjs

i am new to 3D technologies in HTML and javascript.i come to mainly two approaches.one is using WebGL and second is using library like processingjs and Paper js can any one please guideline which approach will be better for performance reason etc.Please guideline!!

Comment: I've used WebGL and found that it works very nicely. The three.js (http://threejs.org) library is very good.

Comment: what is the use of Processingjs ??it is also a library for WebGL ??

Comment: It does use WebGL (http://processingjs.org/articles/RenderingModes.html) so any of processing.js or three.js will work nicely.

Comment: Asking for library/sample/tutorial recommendations is (in general) not what this site is for; this question is at serious risk of being put on hold if not improved.

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion of course but...

I'd avoid Processingjs. Because Processing was based on Java and Processingjs tries to run all the Java based Processing programs it's arguably not really JavaScript nor is it HTML. It's an implementation of Processing designed to run in the browser. It uses lots of shortcuts with magic functions, magic globals, magic inputs, that aren't really going to teach you HTML or JavaScript.

Paper.js doesn't seem to have much 3D related stuff so that's not really an option since you implied you wanted to do 3D.

Going directly to the lowest level, WebGL, will give you the most perf but there's a huge learning curve so you lose the perf of being productive.

So my recommendation would be [three.js](http://threejs.org). Lots of examples, lots of users, lots of people to ask for help. It's very easy to get something 3D quickly up and running.